# Change background color of body with console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

How can i change the background color of the `body` by using the developer console of my browser? I tried it with: `document.body.style.backgroundColor('black');`

and `document.body.style.backgroundColor=black;`

But nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: `document.body.style.backgroundColor='black'` works but `backgroundColor('black');` is not correct because it's not a function

Comment: Oh, i actually used `black` instead of `'black'` -.- thank you!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pz0tb427/

Comment: wow, im definitely tired... i mean i used `document.body.style.backgroundColor=black;` after using quotes it is working, thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
```